# Why does Wireless function key not effect the wireless card but only Bluetooth?

Tags: 12.10, wireless, shortcut-keys, bluetooth, function-keys

My wireless card is switched off at start up of my computer and I cannot switch it on with function key. It only switches on or off the Bluetooth instead.

Is there any other key that opens the wireless that is not shown like the keyboard on my laptop or is there any other problem about the settings?

Comment: Also it appears you're having problems with your wireless card not being recognized, and not a problem with the wireless card not being turned on with the function keys.

Comment: Please be more specific, like explain here ;)
http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into (see section wireless card)

Answer (score 1):

to make sure that your wireless is not affected by the wireless function key, you can  type in a terminal

```
rfkill list
```

then press the wireless function key
then type again the same command.

if you are still "hard blocked" then your key combination is not correctly assigned and you can manage it with xdotool.

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

xdotool is powerful tool to simulate and manage event with your mouse / keyboard.

use xindkeys if you want a GUI